# no such file or directory, killed in fstream c++

Tags: c++

I am new to C++.

I was trying to read a file using `fstream`.

here is the code,

I put the file inside the a.out directory but still cannot read it, where is my mistake?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
   std::ifstream myfile("my.txt");
   int a, b;
   while(myfile>>a>>b)
   std::cout<<a<<b;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: is it intended that `my` is not declared? is you SCCE not the same as the real code?

Comment: what do you mean you can't read it? what's happening? what does "my.txt" contain?

Comment: I got an error msg, please look at the title of my post

Comment: What happens when you give the full path instead of "my.txt" ?

Comment: do you have the right privileges to read the file?

Comment: @user1701840 try running your program with `sudo`. ie `sudo ./a.out`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the file is located in the current directory of the `.exe`. This is usually the same directory as where the `.exe` is located on your harddrive.

If you don't know what the current directory is, I recommended you use the full path.

Comment: The file should be placed in the current directory (i.e. what `pwd` indicates), not related to the `.exe` or `.out`.

Comment: @Caesar nobody appreciates sarcasm.

Comment: @TaylorFlores Well I don't really understand what you meant by "this isn't an answer", what else does it look like? Maybe you don't agree with it but that doesn't mean it is not an answer.

Comment: @neuront, I think Caesar's answer implied the usage of a Windows environment. And, consequently, it is true in that context.

Comment: @Caesar the OP just hasn't given enough information for anyone to give an answer that is much more than speculation. For example, he's using `.out`. Maybe he's using Linux. Maybe he just doesn't have privileges to read the file? And on top of that, he already stated that his files were in the same directory

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   char* name = get_current_dir_name();
   std::cout << "Current Working Dir: " << name << "\n";
   free(name);

   std::ifstream myfile("my.txt");
   if (!myfile))
   {
       std::cout << "Failed to open file\n";
       exit(1);
   }
   int a, b;
   while(myfile>>a>>b)
   {
       std::cout<<a<<b;
   } 
   return 0;
}
```